# How can i change the step for a Plotly saved image?

Tags: python, graph, plotly, step

Im trying to figure out how I can change the step in my Plotly saved image.. right now the step is "3 hours" but i would like to change it to an hourly interval.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-xaxis-dtick - set it to 3600000 (milliseconds in an hour)